# Zeroconfig/Bonjour/dns-sd: How to translate local. hostname into IP address

Tags: bonjour, zeroconf, dns-sd

When I register new service with DNS-SD api in C and then try to discover this service on another computer in my LAN, I am getting after resolving this discovered service something like this:

[image]

Here hostname is: `Michal's-iMac-5k.local.`

How this translates to IP addrees, or how to use it to connect via TCP socket?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the hostname - it doesn't contain the apostrophe.

You can translate hostname to IP using CFHost
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/ResolvingDNSHostnames.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012543-SW2

and create a connection using this
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW4

or this
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1652/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008977